# How to bind Controls to Data, based on seletced item of ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am having trouble understanding how to bind data to some controls.

From the image below, I have *n* objects in a list that I want to be editable, but I don't want *n* amount of controls. I want to select which object from the combo box - so that I can reuse one set of controls.

I have bound data to my combo box, and bound data to a grid view - 'easy'.
**But** my `numericalUpDown` doesn't have a `DataSource` member.

How can I bind it?

And, would I change the binding when `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()` is called? If not, what is a good way to do this?

Thank you for any advice.

[image]

Comment: do a quick google search on how to `Bind data to ComboBox Winforms`

Comment: Sorry buddy, I said I have bound to a combo form, I said that was easy.

Comment: You don't need `DataSource` on your `NumericUpDown` controls. You should add a binding to their `DataBindings` collection, using designer or using code.

Comment: DataBindings, ok - I assume this is because it is a singular form rather than a 'container' like datagridview or combobox. Thank you.

Comment: Windows Forms can take advantage of two types of data binding: simple binding and complex binding. Take a look at [Types of Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: You keep using the word "form" when I think you mean "control". Kinda confusing since "form" means something else.

Comment: Yes my mistake, sorry, I understand the difference but it's new to me so I used the wrong term. I'll edit the question!

Comment: What is the type of object which you want to edit? Is it a row of `DataTable` or is it a plain C# class like `Fruit`? What's the data source of `ComboBox`?

Comment: I will answer my own question, I solved it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best or neatest way, but it definitely works and gives me what I needed.

I believe I need to clear the binding each time, when the selected object I am binding to changes.

The below code clears any existing bindings, and binds the control to the selected data object, binding the `Text` property of the control to the `Xpos` value of the object.

Taking the index value of the combo box, and then using it to access the object that we want in the list.

Within `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

pos_xUpDown.DataBindings.Clear();
pos_xUpDown.DataBindings.Add("Text", objectlist[index], "Xpos");

pos_yUpDown.DataBindings.Clear();
pos_yUpDown.DataBindings.Add("Text", objectlist[index], "Ypos");

pos_zUpDown.DataBindings.Clear();
pos_zUpDown.DataBindings.Add("Text", objectlist[index], "Zpos");
```